# need an expert view on my code javascript

Tags: javascript

I am doing a ternary operator check to see if a certain element is found on the document and set some style and property which will later modify based on other conditions related to user input.
but if the active page does not have those elements I don't want the javascript though error claiming "cant set disabled for null value".

so I use a ternary operator with an array to set multiple values for the element in the case it is found on the page.
my question is am I doing it right or there is a better way ???

```
 submitCodeContent ? [
  (submitCodeContent.disabled = true),
  (submitCodeContent.style.backgroundColor = "#886A6C"),
   ]
   : submitCodeContent;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only use the conditional operator when you need to use the *resulting expression*. If you just want to perform operations if a particular condition is met, use `if`/`else`. Here, you just need

```
if (submitCodeContent) {
  submitCodeContent.disabled = true;
  submitCodeContent.style.backgroundColor = "#886A6C";
}
```

Using the conditional operator when you don't need the result is confusing to readers of the code, and should be avoided.

Comment: sure... I could use that but I have lots of variables to deal with and the ternary looks clean in my code then I wanna preserve consistency.

Comment: If you want to be consistent, I'd recommend starting with a *good style* and being consistent with that. If you have other places in the code where you're using the conditional operator as a replacement for `if`/`else`, I'd recommend fixing all of those areas too. Consider using a linter to enforce a desired style, eg: [eslint](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-expressions)

Comment: thanks tho. I'll take your answer if no better option.